# Linear transformation of a saturated vector

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, geometry

The problem statement is as following:

If we use sat :$\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to denote the standard saturation function, which is
\begin{align}
\text{sat}(s) = \text{sign}(s)\; \text{min}\{ 1,\left|s\right| \}.
\end{align}

If there is a vector $\boldsymbol{u} \in \mathbb{R}^{4}$ and $\boldsymbol{u} = \left[ u_1 \;u_2 \; u_3 \; u_4\right]^T$, we define
\begin{align}
\text{sat}(\boldsymbol{u}) = \left[ \text{sat}(u_1) \;\; \text{sat}(u_2)  \;\; \text{sat}(u_3) \;\; \text{sat}(u_4)\right]^T \in \mathbb{R}^4.
\end{align}

And there is a full-rank real number matrix (or linear transformation) $T \in \mathbb{R}^{4 \times 4}$, let $\boldsymbol{y} = T\text{sat}(\boldsymbol{u}),\; \boldsymbol{y}\in\mathbb{R}^4$. And we know that $\text{sat}(\boldsymbol{u})$ represents a four-dimensional cube. The question is what would $\boldsymbol{y}$ look like in four-dimensional space? Or what is the "bounday" of the set defined by vector $\boldsymbol{y}$?

I am an engineering background student, and I was wondering if there is some advanced geometric knowledge that can solve this problem easily. Thank you!

Comment: The resulting set is the convex hull of the $16$ points $T(\pm 1, ..., \pm 1)^T$.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to prove this?

Comment: Sure, $C=\{ \operatorname{sat} u \}_{u \in \mathbb{R}^4} = \operatorname{co} \{ \pm e_1\pm ...\pm e_4\}$. Since $T$ is linear, we have $TC = \operatorname{co} \{  T(e_1\pm ...\pm e_4)\}$.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if you can recommend me a textbook or other material which introduces explicitly the convex hull and its properties?

Comment: "Convex Optimization" by Boyd & Vandenberghe is a nice introduction.